# One-vs-one SVM in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svm

I wish to implement multi-class SVM using one-vs-one method on fisheriris data in MATLAB.

How can I do so ?

Comment: (-1) it's only courtesy to upvote for those that spend some of their time to help you ...

Comment: Downvoting to make others upvote too is bad ... was'nt available to upvote..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) library for SVMs.

You can train an svm with:

```
model = svmtrain(features, labels);
```

and make predictions:

```
predictions = svmpredict(features);
```

By default, if there are multiple values in 'labels', libsvm does 1vs1 classification.